# Jquery find failed to find element without wrapping it with a parent element

Tags: jquery

jquery seems to not able to find an element without it being wrapped around a parent element.

```
var data = '<div id="target"> This is what I have </div>';
var result = $(data).find("#target").text();
alert("Without targetParent =>" + result);   //Get empty result

data = '<div id="targetParent"><div id="target"> This is what I have </div></div>';
result = $(data).find("#target").text();
alert("With targetParent =>" + result);     // Get the "target" element
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z5roxurq/

Wonder why so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method search for descendant element within the selector. To filter element within the selected elements use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter)** method.

```
var result = $(data).filter("#target").text();
```

```js
var data = '<div id="target"> This is what I have </div>';
var result = $(data).filter("#target").text();
alert("Without targetParent =>" + result); //Get empty result
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATE :**
If you want to get the HTML code then get **[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)** property from it from its dom object.

```
var result = $(data).filter("#target")[0].outerHTML;
```

```js
var data = '<div id="target"> This is what I have </div>';
var result = $(data).filter("#target")[0].outerHTML;
alert("Without targetParent =>" + result); //Get empty result
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If there is only single tag then there is no need of **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter)** method instead get dom object using index.

```
var result = $(data)[0].outerHTML;
```

```js
var data = '<div id="target"> This is what I have </div>';
var result = $(data)[0].outerHTML;
alert("Without targetParent =>" + result); //Get empty result
```

Comment: I would like the result to include the target element.  So, instead of only return "This is what I have", I would like it to return  "<div id="target"> This is what I have </div>".  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The outerHTML is working in jsfiddle.  But I'm getting "Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined" in my app.  Probably because my jquery version is not up to date.

Comment: I ended up using var htmlDoc=new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html");  var result = htmlDoc.getElementById("target").outerHTML; to get the element.

Answer (score 0):

By definition:

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

https://api.jquery.com/find/